# MaterialUI Data-Grid Loading Animation Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI Data-Grid, and I'm running a tutorial grid for server-side data access. This is written in React, and I'm having a problem that the loading circle is permanently spinning. I set a breakpoint in `React.useEffect` and I see it getting hit over and over and over. `handlePageChange` doesn't seem to be participating in the infinite loop.

Thinking about this a little, I feel that the state is changing which triggers the whole thing to execute again, hence the loop. What is the condition supposed to be to stop the thing?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

function loadServerRows(page, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data.rows.slice(page * 5, (page + 1) * 5));
    }, Math.random() * 500 + 100); // simulate network latency
  });
}

export default function App() {

  const data = {
    rows: [
      { id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World' },
      { id: 2, col1: 'XGrid', col2: 'is Awesome' },
      { id: 3, col1: 'Material-UI', col2: 'is Amazing' },
    ],
    columns: [
      { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150 },
      { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150 },
    ],
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6
  }

  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const handlePageChange = (params) => {
    setPage(params.page);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    (async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const newRows = await loadServerRows(page, data);

      if (!active) {
        return;
      }

      setRows(newRows);
      setLoading(false);
    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [page, data]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={data.columns}
        pagination
        pageSize={5}
        rowCount={100}
        paginationMode="server"
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        loading={loading}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what version of material-ui/data-grid are you using?
I found this post because my loading overlay doesn't work at all. I can use the same code and add a CircularProgress elsewhere and know my call to the server and setting loading to true and then false all works. But, never in the grid. Never in any of 20 or so grids this app utilizes. I'm using "^4.0.0-alpha.22".

Comment: "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.23",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code **data** changes on each render. As an option, you can store data with *useRef* (or just make it global moving out of component):

```
import React from 'react'
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid'


function loadServerRows(page, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data.rows.slice(page * 5, (page + 1) * 5))
    }, Math.random() * 500 + 100) // simulate network latency
  })
}

function App() {
  const data = React.useRef({
    rows: [
      { id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World' },
      { id: 2, col1: 'XGrid', col2: 'is Awesome' },
      { id: 3, col1: 'Material-UI', col2: 'is Amazing' },
    ],
    columns: [
      { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150 },
      { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150 },
    ],
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6
  })
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0)
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)

  const handlePageChange = (params) => {
    setPage(params.page)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    (async () => {
      setLoading(true)
      const newRows = await loadServerRows(page, data.current)

      if (!active) {
        return
      }

      setRows(newRows)
      setLoading(false)
    })()

    return () => {
      active = false
    }
  }, [page, data])

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={data.current.columns}
        pagination
        pageSize={5}
        rowCount={100}
        paginationMode="server"
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        loading={loading}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: One thing to consider - when things fail  (such as bad response from server, no internet connection), this won't set loading to false. The setLoading(false) part should be (async())().finally(() => setLoading(false)) that way guaranteed to run.